# How to get current URL in Flutter Web App

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

How can I get the current URL in a Flutter Web App on which the user of the web app currently is?

For example:

app1.website.com
app2.website.com

According to the result of the current URL on which the user of the web app currently is, I want to show different content.

Answer (score 55):

This will get you the current url.

```dart
Uri.base
```

From the docs:

> When running in a browser this is the current URL of the current page (from window.location.href).
> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/base.html

Comment: It's not platform agnostic though. For platforms that are not web it returns the location of the application in the file system ...

Answer (score 37):

You can find it like this:

```
import 'dart:html';

var url = window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 7):

I simply wanted the first part to know if I was on a main domain or subdomain to create links with.

```
  Uri.base.origin
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the javascript code, like this:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

FlatButton(
  child: Text("Button"),
  onPressed: () {
    print(js.context['location']['href']);
    js.context.callMethod("alert", [js.context['location']['href']]);
  },
)
```

Answer (score 2):

https://dart.dev/interop/js-interop/package-web

It is now recommended to use `package:web` instead of `dart:html`.

`web` is a package and should to be added to the dependencies:

```
dependencies:   
  web: ^0.5.0
```

Then in the dart file:

```
import 'package:web/web.dart' as web;

var url = web.window.location.href;
```

Comment: The actual import is:
`import 'package:web/web.dart' as web; `

and the dependency:
`dependencies:
  web: ^0.5.0`

Answer (score 1):

`Uri.base.path` - to the current path on Navigator