# How to Autofill Login details in websites using Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am developing a Password Manager Application for android and a chrome Extension With the use of Flutter but problem is that I don't know how to fill login credentials automatically when user visits to the website. For example, If user store the login ID and password for [www.gmail.com](http://www.gmail.com) Site then whenever user open above site then automatically login id and password need to feel also we can sort the password list in our extension according to the respective site opened in a web browser.

If anyone have idea about it, please give some guidance to me.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for it?

Comment: Actually I was busy in my other project so I haven't work on that, you can try below solution if it work then remaind me as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AutofillGroup](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutofillGroup-class.html) like so:

```
AutofillGroup(
  child: TextFormField(          
    autofillHints: [AutofillHints.password],
    ... 
  ),
),
```

Here are the [hint types](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AutofillHints-class.html):

Comment: But how can I check which website is open in browser? I want to sort the login details according to webpage open in the browser.

Comment: My apologies - I misunderstood what you were looking for. I think this might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57873887/12132021

Comment: Thank you for reply, I surely try it!