# Get url for specific screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to get the url of a specific screen or widget in my flutter app to share with my friends.

I have an app showing some posts and I want to get the url of a specific post and share it to open that post directly in my app.
Such as the URL of the Facebook post, ...etc

Comment: You can get the current URL of the page your on using https://stackoverflow.com/q/56187279/12349734 that should help you.

Comment: No.. my app is android app not web app

Answer (score 0):

using firebase_dynamic_links in flutter

Comment: firebase_dynamic_links are being deprecated and won't work after August 25, 2025.

Comment: But my app is not using Firebase.. is it necessary to use it?