# Flutter Web: How to Extract Parameters from URL in a Web App?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am coding with Flutter and trying to develop a web app. I have already integrated my project with Firebase.

I want the following functionality:
If entered into the URL like this
http://localhost:56485/#/undangan/daffa/nanda

It should display the text "daffa and nanda."

If entered into the URL like this
http://localhost:56485/#/undangan/saya/kamu

It should display the text "saya and kamu."

Answer (score 1):

1. If you don't already have a `Uri` object, use [`Uri.parse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/parse.html) or [`Uri.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/tryParse.html) to create a `Uri` object from an URL string.
2. Use [`Uri.fragment`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/fragment.html) to access the URI fragment (everything after the `#`).
3. From here you either can use a regular expression or a [Dart pattern](https://dart.dev/language/patterns) to parse the fragment.

For example, using a regular expression:

```dart
  var uri = Uri.parse('http://localhost:56485/#/undangan/daffa/nanda');
  var re = RegExp(
    r'^'
    r'/undangan/'
    r'(?<parameter1>[^/]+)'
    r'/'
    r'(?<parameter2>[^/]+)'
    r'(/.*)?'
    r'$',
  );

  var m = re.firstMatch(uri.fragment);
  if (m != null) {
    print('parameter1: ${m.namedGroup('parameter1')}');
    print('parameter2: ${m.namedGroup('parameter2')}');
  }
```

Or using a Dart pattern:

```dart
  var uri = Uri.parse('http://localhost:56485/#/undangan/daffa/nanda');
  if (uri.fragment.split('/')
      case [
        'undangan',
        String parameter1,
        String parameter2,
        ...,
      ]) {
    print('parameter1: $parameter1');
    print('parameter2: $parameter2');
  }
```

Comment: Nice. And to get the current URL, use `Uri.base`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187279/how-to-get-current-url-in-flutter-web-app) answer.